# Slider on bar that indicates a specific value

Tags: visualforce

I have 3 integer values:  a minimum, a maximum and a value between them. Now I want to show, inside a visualforce page, these 3 values on a bar with an indicator (e.g. a slider) on the specific value between the min and max. The bar should be totaly passive (i.e. the user can't move the slider but only see the value).

I don't know how to achieve that. Someone could give me an hint ? Below you find an image of what I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: I think you can use one of the many slides java-script libraries available for this.

Answer (score 1):

In all "modern" browsers (see [this chart](http://caniuse.com/#search=range)), you can use an input of type "range" to specify a slider. You can also choose to disable it as you would any input element, which may be perfect for your case. Please note that the visual appearance will differ with each browser if you choose this route.

Example:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="20" step="2" value="8" disabled="true" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

Chrome:

[image: Chrome Showing a Slider]

IE Edge:

[image: IE Edge Showing a Slider]

Of course, if you want to do a custom slider, pictured like in your question, you could use CSS, SVG, or a canvas to draw the element, or any of the various JavaScript chart libraries out there. I'm not going to work out a specific example, but it's definitely possible.